# Hi, Is fabric can measure total content view in a scrolling page? I just looking to track the impressions of some content in my social app

Tags: android, ios, analytics, google-fabric, impressions

Is there any analytics tool that can measure/track the total view of a content in a scrollable page?

I just looking to track the impressions of some content in my social app.
So it could track the content view when it shows in the screen after the user scrolling down the page and back to scrolling up the page.

Answer (score 2):

Paul from Fabric here. I'd recommend using a [Content View](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-events.html#content-view) with the time of the view as a custom attribute. From that data, you'll be able to track which content is viewed and when. Hope this helps!